# bugzilla 500 error

Tags: bugzilla

I have setup bugzilla 3.6.4 on my centOs 5 based on the instruction provided http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/installation.html . I chose mod_perl approach to execute it. I see my bugzilla running , when I go to create a new account , i get token url through mail. But once I fill the form and submit , 500 error occurs and same happens with forgot password .
No clue why it is happening .

Help is really really appreciated .

Thanks a ton in advance
-DD

Answer (score 1):

If you get an 500 error, check out your web servers log. It usually contains a more detailed error message compared to the plain message that the browser displays. If I remember it correctly CentOS puts logs into /var/log/httpd but you might have defined another path inside your httpd.conf or your virtual server files.

Comment: Yeah  i checked the error log but , not getting any clue .log throws same thing when a successful mail sent by bugzilla and when it throws 500 error when i tred reseting my password. Here is the smaple:"Apache2::SizeLimit httpd process too big, exiting at SIZE=382436/0 KB  SHARE=3900/0 KB  UNSHARED=378536/70000 KB  REQUESTS=2 LIFETIME=0 seconds"
Admin login is jus not working . say i created admin with email :"abc@gmail.com", name=abc and passwor="xyz". It throws error by saying invalid login for the same.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason on my installations using Ubuntu Server, Bugzilla 3.6.4 never worked well for me. 
I so recomend the Bugzilla 4.0 upgrade. [Installation Guide](http://www.microsumol.com/2011/02/bugzilla-installation-upgrade-guide/)